javascript : why can i not get routes from url?
i have 2 pages : index.html ans app.js

index.html looks like
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
    <title>Bank App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- This is where you'll work -->
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <template id="login">
        <h1>Bank App</h1>
        <section>
          <a href="/dashboard">Login</a>
        </section>
    </template>

    <template id="dashboard">
        <header>
          <h1>Bank App</h1>
          <a href="/login">Logout</a>
        </header>
        <section>
          Balance: 100$
        </section>
        <section>
          <h2>Transactions</h2>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Object</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        </section>
      </template>

  </body>
</html>


app.js looks like
const routes = {
    '/login': { templateId: 'login' },
    '/dashboard': { templateId: 'dashboard' },
  };

function updateRoute() {

    const path = window.location.pathname;
    const route = routes[path]
    console.log(route.templateId)

    const template = document.getElementById(route.templateId);
    const view = template.content.cloneNode(true);
    const app = document.getElementById('app');
    app.innerHTML = '';
    app.appendChild(view);
  }


updateRoute()



when i run on local (live) server in vs code, and hit localhost:5500/login, i am not getting the login template from index.html
any help please to know why ?

Does your local live server serve the HTML in the index.html file when you access /login?

when i hit http://127.0.0.1:5500/login i got : Cannot GET /login

however when i hit http://127.0.0.1:5500/zbank/index.html i got "Loading..."

Well, usually, out of the box, webservers serve the file at the path that is requested. So if you try to access /login then it will look for a login file which doesn't exist. It doesn't magically serve the index.html for any any path you request.

Getting "loading" for that URL makes sense. The pathname for that URL is /zbank/index.html, which doesn't exist in your routes object.

since i defined object called routes on my js file, which is intend to make the mapping, why it is not working ? what is messing ?

If the server doesn't send the index.html file, how can app.js run to do anything?

what happens if you "hit" (whatever that means) http://127.0.0.1:5500/zbank/login

i got "Cannot GET /zbank/login"

FYI: i am following this workshop : https://github.com/MohamedBenighil/js/blob/main/7-bank-project/1-template-route/README.md#creating-routes

but your index.html is in /zbank right? So, your server needs to send that if the requested resource /login isn't found ... it's not clear what you are running as a server, nor your file structure, so, it's a bit hard to help

why zbank even in the path - you're not following the 7-bank-template very well are you

the zbank is just a folder on my vscode containing my 2 files : index.html and app.js

i used local server to vscode. if you are windows user : hit crt+shitft+P then hit 'live server'

if you hit localhost:5500/login browser will look for file named login.html, but since you only have index.html its going to be 404 error, you can achieve what you want with query parameters localhost:5500/?path=login like this, and then look for this parametr like you did with pathname

i would like to use pathname instead of query parameters, because this what it did in tutorial i followed, and i would like to know what is messing on my js code ?

@Mohamed, I use Windows + VSCode and there's no 'live server' for me. This can be one of your plugins. It will not work for everyone.

@Mohamed, your HTML + JS will not work at all. At least not with just this two files like they are now. If you change your <a> tags to have their href="javascript:updateRoute('/login')" for example, your app should work if you load your index.html directly on your browser (without using a server).

give a link to this tutorial? because you will not achieve what you wantwith only this two files

https://github.com/MohamedBenighil/js/blob/main/7-bank-project/1-template-route/README.md#creating-routes

it will work only with npx lite-server like they do in tutorial, vs code live server not going to work

I think this is because your app.js is only processed when you load index.html. Since you do not load this file, app.js is not called and nothing happens.
One solution could be to do it via parameters in the URL: https://www.semrush.com/blog/url-parameters/
